# PSM Propensity Score Matching Combination of exact and full matching

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I would like to compare two groups (one treatment group and one control group). In both groups one can identify three different subgroups (let's call them Index-subgroup). I would first like to compare TG and CG without further selection of these three Index-subgroups. Afterwards, however, I would like to compare TG and CG, exclusively on each of these three Index-subgroups respectively.

Is it a good idea to use PSM four times now or is there a better solution? (see below)

1. No further selection of Index-subgroup **and then** performing matching
2. Exclusively selecting Index-subgroup A from my sample **and then** performing matching
3. Exclusively selecting Index-subgroup B from my sample **and then** performing matching
4. Exclusively selecting Index-subgroup C from my sample **and then** performing matching

I thought of combining full matching on all covariates with exact matching on the three Index-subgroups respectively but am unsure whether this is a valid approach. If so, how can I calculate the treatment effect per Index-subgroup?

My respective R code is (for exclusively selecting Index-subgroupA):

```
matched_dataNew <- matchit(Group ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + IndexSubgroupA + IndexSubgroupB + IndexSubgroupC + x5 + x6 + x7, method = "full", distance = "glm", exact = ~ IndexSubgroupA, data = data_spss)
```

Glad for any help.

Comment: What makes propensity scores a good approach in this setting?  And note there are many problems with matching.  See for example https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity.html.

Comment: I am aware of the limitations and weaknesses of PSM but I am interested in the Hazard ratios of the two groups which I will obtain from survival analyses after matching. And matching is needed as the groups differ on the covariates.

Comment: Those hazards ratios are nearly impossible to interpret and you'll find that they are less likely to be constant over $t$ than had you used covariate adjustment.  Differing on covariates is no reason to match exactly in unusually high-dimensional settings.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to do matching once with an exact matching constraint. You can either do this by doing a seperate matching step wihin each subgroup or a single round of matching with subgroup supplied as an exact matching variable. In `MatchIt`, both methods do the same thing; the only difference is whether the propensity score is estimated in the full sample or within each subgroup. If you use a parametric propensity score model (e.g., logistic regression, the default) and include interactions between each predictor and subgroup membership, the propensity scores will also be the same between the two methods.

You can assess balance in each subgroup, then fit a single outcome model and use a marginal effects procedure to extract the subgroup effect estimates. The way you wrote your models is a bit confusing because based on your description, I would expect you to have a single variable the contains your index subgroup membership (A, B, or C). I'll try to write somne example code that will help perform the analysis I think yo uintend to.

```r
# Do the matching with a fully interacted PS model
matched_dataNew <- matchit(Group ~ IndexSubgroup * (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7),
                           method = "full", distance = "glm", exact = ~ IndexSubgroup,
                           data = data_spss)         

# Assess balance on each subgroup
library("cobalt")
bal.tab(matched_dataNew, cluster = "IndexSubgroup", stats = c("m", "k"))

# If balance is good, estimate the effect
md <- match.data(matched_dataNew)

fit <- lm(y ~ Group * IndexSubgroup, data = md,
          weights = weights)

library("marginaleffects")
avg_comparisons(fit, variables = "Group",
                by = "IndexSubgroup",
                wts = "weights",
                vcov = ~subclass,
                newdata = subset(md, Group == 1))

# Compare effects across groups
avg_comparisons(fit, variables = "Group",
                by = "IndexSubgroup",
                wts = "weights",
                vcov = ~subclass,
                newdata = subset(md, Group == 1),
                hypothesis = "revpairwise")

# Estimate a single marginal treatment effect
avg_comparisons(fit, variables = "Group",
                wts = "weights",
                vcov = ~subclass,
                newdata = subset(md, Group == 1))
```

I explain how to do the other method (matching in subgroups separately) in [this blog post](https://ngreifer.github.io/blog/subgroup-analysis-psm/).

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot! When assessing the balance with the bal.tab function, I am getting the error message 'no applicable method for 'as.cluster' applied to an object of class "logical"' and am unsure how to respond to this.

Comment: Moreover, I am having a some problems following this combined method of full and exact matching. My covariates that I intend to match the groups on include three dichotomous variables that indicate the index subgroups (+ 7 other variables). I did a matching procedure with full matching on all 10 covariates. I am interpreting the treatment effect that I am getting from this calculation in this way that it is apparent for all subgroups of my TG and CG as the subgroups were part of covariates that I matched upon. So overall the treatment has effect x.

Comment: Now, when I want to do an analysis of the different subgroups, I am not sure whether I should include the dichotomous variables that indicate the subgroup-belongingness in the covariates to do the matching on. I feel like this would not make too much sense as I am matching on the Subgroups in an exact fashion which makes including those three variables as matched covariates redundant, if not even overmatched. On the other hand does subgroup-belongingness influence my outcome as well as treatment (following Austin, 2011).

Comment: Please submit a bug report [here](https://github.com/ngreifer/cobalt/) with a reproducible example and I will fix it.

Comment: I still don't understand your design I guess. Do you have 3 subgroups, or 2x2x2 = 8 subgroups? And yes, you should include the subgrouping variable in the propensity score model. You still need to get the PS model right for the matching to be effective. I don't know what you mean by "overmatched".

Comment: I have three subgroups. My study is about recidivism, so I have one subgroup with homicide index offenses, the next one with sexual offenses and the last subgroup contains other violent offenses. All in all I am looking at the outcome of recidivism in a group of treated offenders vs untreated. In my matching variables I include all these three subgroups in the ps model.

Comment: Therefore, I coded them dichotomously: index_homicide (y/n), index_sex (y/non and index_otherviolent (y/n). The variable that I'd use for exact matching would then entail one categorical variable with the subgroup-belongigness (eg homicide, sex, other violent offenses). So my code is now looking like this: matched_dataNew <- matchit(Group ~ IndexSubgroup * (x1 + x2 + index_homicide + index_sex + index_otherviolent + x6 + x7),
                           method = "full", distance = "glm", exact = ~ IndexSubgroup,
                           data = data_spss)         
Is this logically correct?

Comment: If you have 3 subgroups, why don't you just have a single categorical variable that contains subgroup membership, like one would for, e.g., race? If coded as a factor, R automatically expands it into the appropriate binary variables for any models but retains the categorical nature when used in other purposes (e.g., for defining the exact matching variable). So your code is not correct; you include subgroup twice in the PS model part, when it only needs to be there once. The code I included in my answer is correct, with a 3-level categorical variable called `IndexSubgroup`.

Comment: I guess I do not understand what the function (combining full and exact matching) does. Am I right in thinking that this function matches the groups on the covariates provided in brackets fully for each of the subgroups? Hence, subgroup-belongingness would not be entailed in the propensity score calculation, correct?

Comment: Moreover, I am trying to estimate the hazard ratios for each subgroup based on the matched groups. Can someone recommend any r vignettes that give an example of estimating HRs in subgroups?

Comment: Combining exact matching and full matching splits the data into subgroups and then does a separate round of full matching in each subgroup. Full matching is done on the propensity score. Including an interaction between subgroup membership and the other covariates in the PS model is equivalent to estimating a separate PS model for each subgroup. So my code essentially runs a separate PS estimation and full matching for each subgroup, extracts the matched dataset, and estimate subgroups effects and an overall effect.

Comment: Thank you. And with which code would I be able to get the HRs for each of the three subgroups (knowing that HRs have a lot of limitations)? I can only find the code for estimating an overall HR.

Comment: As I commented on your other question, I don't think you should use HRs. They are not the only, but possibly one of the worst, ways to describe effects for survival outcomes. I'm not an expert on survival analysis so I can't give you specific code.